# Jenkins exclude time(s) 2am-6am from Build Execution? - maybe use cron?

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-plugins

My Jenkins job executes Webdriver tests continuously however i need to exclude the hours of 2am between 6am, possible?

I know there are useful links available: 
https://crontab.guru/#*_5-23_*_*_*

I added the following but dosnt seem to work:
* 6-23 * * *
* 1-2 * * *
* 0-1 * * *

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well you need to exclude the hours from 2am to 6am (both included).

Something like this:

```
* 0-1,7-23 * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

Implemented the following which I can confirm works:
* 0,1,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 * * *